# SOAPClient Error: Could not connect to host on PHP 7.0 and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, soap, wsdl, laravel-5.1

I am having issues connecting to a WSDL via SOAPClient on my Laravel application in a server with PHP 7.0. I have tested the following code on my local server using PHP 5.6 and it works. Both are running Linux; my local server is running Kubuntu and the other server is running CentOS 7.

```
var $client;

function __construct(){
    ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',WSDL_CACHE_NONE);
    ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', 0);

    $this->client = new SoapClient(env('WSDL_SOLMAN02_TEST'),
        ['login'=>env('SOLMAN_US_TEST'),
         'password'=>env('SOLMAN_PSSWD_TEST'),
         'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
         'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
         'ssl_method' => 'SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv3',
         'trace' => true,
         'exception' => false,
         'stream_context'=> stream_context_create(array(
            'ssl'=> array(
                    'verify_peer'=>false,
                    'verify_peer_name'=>false
                )
            ))
        ]
    );

}
public function updateTicket(Ticket $ticket){

    $incident = $this->createTicketObject($ticket);
    $params = get_object_vars($incident);

    return $this->client->wsdlFunc($params);
}
```

The funny thing is that when I print `dd($this->client->__getFunctions());` the WSDL responds with an array of all the functions that you can call, but when I actually call upon any function, the error is displayed.

I have tried just about everything, from changing every parameter in the connection to changing the php.ini, but nothing has worked. I have downgraded the server to PHP 5.6 and it still doesn't work.

I have also tested WSDL on SOAPUI and it works.

The only difference I find between both environments is that the server with PHP 7.0 has https.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My code was fine, I just had to add the WSDL ip address to /etc/hosts.

Comment: I just specify that at the end of the WSDL you'll find the endpoint url:<soap:address location="http://DOMAIN/rest/of/url"/>, even if the WSDL is loaded by IP, if this endpoint contains the domain instead an IP, it is necesary to include it in /etc/hosts as suecamol says.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem when I upgraded from php v7.2 to v7.3 (docker):
`SOAPClient Error: Could not connect to host`

I tried the solution proposed by @suecamol but it did not work. Looks like php v7.3 changed something with the ssl security.

The solution, that one of my co-worker found, was to add a proper ssl ciphers encryption:

```php
$arrContextOptions= [
        'ssl' => [
            'ciphers' => 'AES256-SHA',
        ]
    ];

$options = [
        ...

        'stream_context' => stream_context_create($arrContextOptions),
    ];


$client = new SoapClient('some wsdl url', $options);
```

Hopefully this can help someone facing this issue.

Comment: Thanks! This works for me. You save me after 6 hours of search.